# I still have access to the review queues

Tags: bug, review

The site is now public but I am still seeing a link to the review queues.

[image]

[image]

I also still have the close vote privilege on ProofAssistants.meta

Can someone please fix?

**Update**:

It's fixed now.

Comment: I cleared my cache and same thing.

Comment: Maybe SE staff forgot how to make sites public.

Comment: Sorry for rolling back your edit @Taylor, but it had an effect on the images.

Comment: No worries! Apologies for the negative effects!